# Logs are left even deleted in code on aws cloudwatch log groups

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm running server on aws ecs fargate.
I wrote logs and cloudwatch printed them.

I deleted logs on codes but still cloudwatch is printing logs.

So I set retention to 1day to remove.. But when I run container logs comeback.

There are cache for logs?
What is the reason?
And How to remove them?

Comment: "I deleted logs on codes but still cloudwatch is printing logs." It sounds like you didn't actually update the docker image running on Fargate with the new code.

Comment: @MarkB thank u for reply. But I updated my codes and pushed images to ecr. I pulled images and checked the image on local by running the containers. But no prints in codes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was old task was left. So I deleted old task then run new task